# Variable is taking Garbage value in spite of initializing it

Tags: c, pointers

I created a function to "Reverse a linked list", for that I initialized an array of pointers of size 3. to implement the code I have to constantly re assign the pointers and for that I created two variables `a` and `b`.

I initialized both the variables but upon printing them for checking if they have the correct value, the second variable is taking up garbage value.

I already tried by directly working with the iterator `i` instead of variables but no luck.

```
int reverseData(struct student **head) {

    struct student *arr[2];

    int i=1,a=2,c=(a+1)%3;  // THIS IS INITIALIZATION OF 'C'

    if(*head==NULL){
        printf("UNDERFLOW\n\n");
        return 0;
    }

    arr[2]=*head;
    arr[1]=arr[2]->next;
    printf("\nexecuted\n");

    if(arr[2]->next!=NULL)
        arr[0]=arr[1]->next;

    arr[2]->next=NULL;

    while(1) {

        printf("\nexecuted while\n");
        printf("\n%d\n", a);
        printf("%d\n", c);            //THIS IS THE FIRST TIME PRINT OF 'C'    

        if(arr[(i+2)%3]->next==NULL)
            break;

        arr[i]->next=arr[a];
        arr[a]=arr[c]->next;

        i=((i>0)?(i-1):2);
        a=(i+1)%3;
        c=(a+1)%3;

    }
    printf("\nwhile exit\n");




    arr[i]->next=arr[a];
    printf("yuhu");
    arr[c]->next=arr[i];

    *head= arr[c];
    printf("done dana done");
    return 0;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1 c     // THIS IS THE LINKED LIST HAVING A NUMBER AND A CHAR[20]
1 b
1 a

1. Insert
2. Delete
3. Reverse
4. Exit
3
executed

executed while

2
6819248      // THIS IS THE VALUE OF C PRINTED

while exit
yuhu
```

Comment: in the output, it is : 2 (then space) then the value of c. it got wrong during my question posting.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: arrays are zero indexed.  The definition of the array `struct student *arr[2];` allows you to reference `arr[0]` and `arr[1]`.  Referencing `arr[2]` is invalid.

Comment: There is no `b` in your code. Do you mean `c`?

Comment: Your code does not produce the output you show us. Please always provide matching output. Together with the MCVE mentioned already by melpomene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the line `arr[2]=*head;`. You've allocated space for 2 items in `arr`, and `arr[2]` would be a **third** item. When you make that assignment, you overwrite some other data, apparently `c`. Increase the allocation to 3 items, or re-think what you're doing.